# Trying to 'alias' a css element selector at run time

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I am trying to set the position of a font awesome icon in an input field at run time.  To do this I had hoped to have the style compute at run time as I've done with other style sheet elements.  However, I am banging my head up against the wall with this one.  I did not include a jfiddle because my problem is trying to make the element dynamic and I don't believe I can do that in a fiddle.

This code works.  The dollar sign appears at the right side of the input box:

```
  <div class="col-md-6 form-control-static">
    <div class="input-icon right">
         <i class="fa fa-dollar"></i>
            <input>
```

Notice that I used "right" to get the icon on the right.  What I want to do is replace this element with a generic element and set that value dynamically in computed css.

So what I really want to say is this:

```
   <div class="input-icon currencyPlacement">
```

And then in the computed style sheet somehow resolve "currencyPlacement" to be "left" or "right" based on conditions that I will compute.

```
   <style>
      .currencyPlacement { ????? }
    </style>
```

I realize that I could set this using javascript and I could also have this compute at the field level.  I thought there might be a better way to effectively alias the element.  Sorry for the long-winded description and thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Can you elaborate `dynamically`? Where is the input for the `left` and `right` would be?

Comment: Thanks so much for your response.  Parts of our stylesheet (including currency symbol and placement) are generated via code as they are dependant on data.  In this example, I want to have the generic element "currencyPlacement" somehow resolve to "right" or "left" in the style sheet.  I am essentially trying to "link" classes (for lack of a better phrase).

Comment: Sorry but CSS cannot detect conditions other than screen sizes for now. You need to try JS. But you can use SASS if required.

Comment: Once again, I am not asking css to detect a condition.  I am trying to generate css.  I am trying to find a way to link currencySymbol to either left or right (which I will generate automatically in my code).  The code to generate the dynamic style is working.

What I am essentially looking for is a way to override/link/alias currencyPlasement so that it resolves to "right" or left".  I can do this via javascript but I'd prefer to do something in css if possible.

Comment: In the style sheet I essentially want to say "currencyPlacement=right" or "currencyPlacement=left".  I have accomplished the same in javascript with this statement:   $('.currencyPlacement').addClass('right');

Answer (score 0):

You said that you generate the whole thing by code. So presumeably your code "knows" the currency and its placement. It seems much more straightforward to me to use your initial approach. Or perhaps instead of "`right`" or "`currencyPlacement`" assign a style that corresponds to the currency, like

`.currUSD, .currEUR, .currATS {` *css to place it right* `}`
`.currXYZ  {` *css to place it left* `}`

And in case you set the currency on the same page, there will be no way around some JS to assign the proper class to that input-field.

**Update**: wrt to your comment: since you insert a FA-Tag related to USD, I assume you know what the currency will be when you build the page. So if you have that knowledge, can't you then make sure the controls appear in the appropriate order, as in this [example](http://www.bootply.com/xi4ukQeO9s#)? I think that would make it much easier - otherwise I would only know how to do with JS, but I see no solution with CSS alone, I'm afraid.

Comment: I think that is kind of the heart of the question.  What css would be equivalent to boostrap "right" or "left"? I want the same result.  For example, if I put it on the left I want the editable text to be just to the right of the dollar sign.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply.  Yes, ultimately I could do much of this at the control level.  We have so many controls that I was trying to avoid that but it is probably necessary.

Comment: I'm sry I couldn't offer a better solution ;-)
BTW: if nothing else comes up, pls. be so kind and accept the reply, so that the question is closed...